# Creating folder with a different name each time

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, web-applications, directory

I have an asp.net c# web application which creates a folder.The web application includes some buttons to change sth in this folder.The web application is hosted at 2008 server. Now I want to make it multi user application. Different users should run this web application with different folder names and they can change something on the folder simultaneously.
How to manage it?

Comment: You could assign each user a Guid stored in session and create/access folders based on that.

Comment: Are you using any form of authentication in your web app? Create/Use a folder with the authentication name/id in it.

Comment: Nope I am not using. Should I use to achive my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Path.GetRandomFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx):

```
var folderName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
```

Comment: Thank you but if I give random file name, how will I change sth on that folder with buttons? For example in a web application when I click button the content of txt file in that folder displays on the text area in the web application. How will I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the folder name based on the current user's ID and a date time stamp. The resulting format would be "hsimpson_2013-11-23_12-23-12-AM" or something along these lines. That way you could always get a list of folders and sort by just the users whose names exist as part of the string or search folders based on a date/time.